# Javascript/API - Best way to call async function to export axios request

Tags: javascript, api, axios

The idea here is to call an API for get the price of sport in organisation.

I'm looking for a way to call it like this way but the const CHOOSE_SPORT seems not to be asynchronous. Is it a way to call it more properly ?

```
export const url = '/api/sport/' 
    
    export const requestApi = async (sport) => {
      return await axios.get(url + sport).then(function(req) {
        console.log(req.data);
        return req.data;
      })
    };
    
     const CHOOSE_SPORT = freeze({ 
      [SPORT.NOW]: await requestApi('football'), 
      [SPORT.TOMORROW]: await requestApi('basketball') ,  
    });
    
    export const prize = (SPORT) => {
      return CHOOSE_SPORT[SPORT] ;
    }
```

Comment: You can't do this because `import` is synchronous.

Comment: You should export an async function that gets the value, and the user of the library can call the function with `await`.

Comment: Is this code in a [JS module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await)? Or is there missing wrapper code around `CHOOSE_SPORT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but requestApi is an asynchronous function, therefore it will return a promise. You can't await outside an async function, you will have to wrap it or use then.

```js
export const url = '/api/sport/'

export const requestApi = async (sport) => {
  return await axios.get(url + sport).then(function (req) {
    console.log(req.data);
    return req.data;
  })
};

async function generateSportLib(SPORT) {
  const now = await requestApi('football');
  const tomorrow = await requestApi('basketball');
  const CHOOSE_SPORT = freeze({
    [SPORT.NOW]: now,
    [SPORT.TOMORROW]: tomorrow,
  });
  return CHOOSE_SPORT;
}

export const prize = async (SPORT) => {
  const CHOOSE_SPORT = await generateSportLib(SPORT);
  return CHOOSE_SPORT; // 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback ! acutally with your solution I get the value of [SPORT.NOW]: now but not for [SPORT.TOMORROW]: tomorrow ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do and how does `SPORT` object look like